# How to stop execution in script which may have been sourced or directly executed

Tags: bash

If my script gets sourced with

```
. ./my_script.sh
source ./my_script.sh
```

then to stop execution in the script, I would use `return`.

If my script is directly executed with

```
./my_script.sh
bash ./my_script.sh
```

then I'd insert an `exit`.

**If I don't know whether the user will source it or directly execute it, how can I cleanly stop the script without killing the terminal it was called from?**

Preferably, the code snippet should be able to terminate the script even if it were placed inside one of the script's functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ec=0 # determine the desired exit code

return $ec 2>/dev/null || exit $ec
```

`return` will succeed if the script is being sourced, otherwise `exit` will kick in. The `2>/dev/null` suppresses the error message in case the script is *not* sourced.

The net effect is that the script will terminate with the desired exit / return code, regardless of whether it was sourced or not.

---

**Update**: The OP wants to be able to exit the script from *inside a function* within the script.

The only way I can think of is to **place all of your script's code in a *subshell*** and call `exit` from inside the functions inside that subshell; then place the `return 2>/dev/null || exit` command *after* the subshell (as the only statement outside the subshell):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

( # subshell to place all code in

  foo() {
    exit 1  # exit the subshell
  }

  foo # invoke the function

)

# Terminate script with exit code from subshell.
ec=$?; return $ec 2>/dev/null || exit $ec
```

Comment: One line of code, awesome!  But, I forgot to say in the question that it would be preferable if it could be executed even from within a function inside the script.  Sorry, I will add that to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to find out which method was used to invoke the script.

```
if [[ "$0" == "bash" ]]; then
   echo "source 'file' was used"
else
   echo "bash 'file' was used"
fi
```

**Update**, In response to comment by @mklement0:

If your script is named `my_script.sh`, you can use

```
b=$(basename "$0")
if [[ "$b" == "my_script.sh" ]]; then
   echo "bash 'file' was used"
else
   echo "source 'file' was used"
fi
```

Comment: Right, I suppose I could put `return` in the first block and `exit` in the second. The downside is that this solution can not be used within a function since return would just return from that function, and not stop the script.

Comment: Another option is to `exit` with different exit codes. Not sure whether that is an option for you.

Comment: My issue is that if I use exit (regardless of exit code), and the user sourced my script, then it would kill their terminal along with the script, and they'd get to see none of my error messages.

Comment: If you source from an interactive _login_ shell - all interactive shells on OSX are login shells, for instance - `$0` will be `-bash`. If `bash` is invoked as `sh` (e.g., via a symlink, as on some platforms), `$0` will be `sh`.

Comment: @mklement0 Good points. Hopefully my update addresses that adequately.

Comment: Honestly, hard-coding the name of the script is asking for trouble; consider using `[[ "$0" == "$BASH_SOURCE" ]] && echo "NOT SOURCED" || echo "SOURCED"` - `$0` and `$BASH_SOURCE` will only be identical if NOT sourced.