# Bash: abort execution of sourced script from function

Tags: bash, shell

I sometimes include this function in my scripts:

```
function abort {
    echo $@; exit 1
}
```

It's nice to have a print-and-exit notation contained in a single command. However, when sourcing scripts, `exit` kills the shell and `return` does nothing from within the function.

How can I redefine `abort()` to work in sourced scripts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you return to a sourced bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666846/how-do-you-return-to-a-sourced-bash-script)

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23749529/how-to-stop-execution-in-script-which-may-have-been-sourced-or-directly-executed

Comment: The short of it: methinks this can't be done in a generic function, UNLESS you place _all your code_ in a _subshell_ and use `exit` there: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/23751042/45375

Comment: @Barmar Not a duplicate of that particular question, since he's asking about it in a function which handles both sourcing and execution and mentions that `return does nothing from within the function`, or more precisely doesn't do what's intended here.